# How to I check if an index of a string is within multiple ranges?

Tags: python

I would like to create a function that counts the number of characters in a string that are within multiple ranges. Let's say the valid characters are:

- between `'a'` and `'f'`
- between `'1'` and `'3'`
- comma `','`

If the function were called `NumInRange(s)`, this is what I would expect from the code. The characters `a`, `1`, `d`, `,`, and `b` are within range so return `5`:

```py
>>> NumInRange("a14d8,b")
5
```

My code is shown below:

```
def NumInRange(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        count=0
        if (ord('a')<=ord(s[i])<=ord('e') or 1<=int(s[i])<=3 or ord(s[i])==ord(',')):
            count=count+1
    return count
```

When I tried my code with only integer it works fine but when I tried it with characters the error message pops up

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

Comment: The int function will only allow you to input numbers. It throws an error when you iterate through the string because its feeding a character to the int function.

Comment: if you are allowed to use regular expression you can make use of re.findall, `import re  print(len(re.findall("[A-Fa-f1-3,]",your_string)))`

Answer (score 7):

- No need to convert to `int` or `ord`, compare the strings directly.
- You instantiated `count` with `0` inside the loop, so even if the code worked you'd always get `0` or `1`.

```
def NumInRange(s):
    count = 0
    for c in s:
        if 'a' <= c <= 'e' or '1' <= c <= '3' or c == ',':
            count += 1
    return count
```

Thanks to the fact that booleans subclass `int`, this can become a nice one-liner using a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
def NumInRange(s):
    return sum('a' <= c <= 'e' or '1' <= c <= '3' or c == ',' for c in s)
```

Also note that since `c` can only be a single character (given that `s` is a string) you can simply do (at the "cost" of "hardcoding" the ranges)

```
def NumInRange(s):
    return sum(c in 'abcde123,' for c in s)
```

Another, completely different approach is a regex:

```
import re

def NumInRange(s):
    return len(re.findall('[a-e1-3,]', s))
```